# how to display binary pdf in xamarin web api

Tags: sql-server, pdf, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

i am using xamarin crossplatform with web api. I have database in which i have binary data of pdf files. I want to display these pdf files.

**Web Api**

```
private Entities1 db = new Entities1();

        public IQueryable<DiagnosticDetailModel> GetDiagnosticDetailModels()
        {
            return db.DiagnosticDetailModels;
        }
```

this above code to get list of table where i have id,reportname,filecontent(byte)

```
 [Route("api/DiagnosticDetail/RetrieveFile/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage RetrieveFile(int id)
    {
DiagnosticDetailModel diagnosticDetailModel = GetFileList(id);
        byte[] img = diagnosticDetailModel.FileContent.ToArray();
        HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(img);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return result;
    }
    private DiagnosticDetailModel GetFileList(int id)
    {
        var DetList = db.DiagnosticDetailModels.Where(p => p.InpatientCodeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
       return DetList;
    }
```

this above code to return file filecontent(byte), i have tested this api its working fine in browser

**Xamarin RestClient**

```
     private const string WebServiceDiagnostic = "http://172.16.4.212:55364/api/DiagnosticDetailModels/";
        private const string WebServiceReport = "http://172.16.4.212:55364/api/DiagnosticDetail/RetrieveFile/";

 public async Task<List<T>> GetDiagnosticAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceDiagnostic);
            var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
            return taskModels;
        }
```

this above is restclient code to get list of data from database

```
public async Task<T> userReport(int id)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceReport + id);
            var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return taskModels;
        }
```

this above code is to get fileContent(byte)

**Xamarin Services**

```
 public async Task<List<DiagnosticDetailModel>> GetReportDetailAsync()
            {
                RestClient<DiagnosticDetailModel> restClient = new RestClient<DiagnosticDetailModel>();
                var employeesList = await restClient.GetDiagnosticAsync();
                return employeesList;
            }

public async Task<DiagnosticDetailModel> ReportAsync(int id)
        {
            RestClient<DiagnosticDetailModel> restClient = new RestClient<DiagnosticDetailModel>();
            var user = await restClient.userReport(id);
            return user;
        }
```

**Xamarin MainVeiwModel**

```
private List<DiagnosticDetailModel> _ReportList;
        public List<DiagnosticDetailModel> ReportList
        {
            get { return _ReportList; }
            set
            {
                _ReportList = value;
                OnPropertChanged();
            }
        }

public MainViewModel()
        {
            InitializeDiagnosticDataAsync();
        }

 public async Task InitializeDiagnosticDataAsync()
        {
            var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();
            ReportList = await employeesServices.GetReportDetailAsync();
        }

private DiagnosticDetailModel _SelectedReport;
        public DiagnosticDetailModel SelectedReport
        {
            get { return _SelectedReport; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedReport = value;
                OnPropertChanged();
            }
        }

public Command GetReport
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();
                   SelectedReport= await employeesServices.ReportAsync(_SelectedReport.InpatientCodeId);
                });
            }
        }
```

**Xamarin main.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="ReportListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ReportList}"
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemTapped="ListViewReport_OnItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="6,6" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding InpatientCodeId}" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="100" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="100"
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Date}"  FontSize="Small" Opacity="0.6" WidthRequest="100"
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Button Text="View" BackgroundColor="Crimson" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="100" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
```

**Xamarin main.cs**

```
    private async void ListViewReport_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                var user = ReportListView.SelectedItem as DiagnosticDetailModel;
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var mainViewModel = BindingContext as MainViewModel;
                    if (mainViewModel != null)
                    {
                        mainViewModel.SelectedReport = user;
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Reports(mainViewModel));
                        ReportListView.SelectedItem = null;
                    }


   }
        }
```

Xamarin Report.xaml

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="18">
        <Button  Text="Update" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Crimson" Command="{Binding GetReport}"/>
        <WebView Source="{Binding SelectedReport.FileContent,Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

in every section i have two parts one is getting list of table and other is to get file which in binary data in table. The program is working fine where i can get list of table and when i click on tap of list i navigate to **Report** page by passing the id, there i have button to **GetReport** and i am trying to get file in webview which i am not able to do.

Answer (score 1):

PDFs in WebView are only supported out of the box by iOS. If you also want to use them in Android and UWP, you need to use for example [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). Take a look at this official Xamarin Forms tutorial, which details how to use pdfjs in Android&UWP and then create a common abstraction you can use in your Xamarin Forms code:

[Display a Local PDF File in a WebView](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf)

The abstraction will look like this:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create (propertyName:"Uri",
            returnType:typeof(string),
            declaringType:typeof(CustomWebView),
            defaultValue:default(string));

    public string Uri {
        get { return (string)GetValue (UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue (UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

so in your shared code you'll just have to specify correct Uri (can be a file path) of your pdf file. To save a file, you also need some custom logic for UWP and common for iOS and Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin#saving-and-loading-files

Comment: so you can i can display binary data in webview? and how webview controller code will look like after i create CustomWebView ?

Comment: just save your binary data as a pdf in your mobile storage and use it as CustomWebView uri.

Comment: I updated my answer with link to file saving tutorial. Please try to do it yourself and post any problems you have